# custom view, canvas.ClipPath and View.TranslationX/Y/Rotation

Tags: android

**EDIT** workaround found

use SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null); even on API 19+

---

I have created a custom view and overriden onDraw. My onDraw routine uses a circle clip path to draw things. This works fine on Android 4+ versions.

When TranslationX/Y or Rotation are set on the custom view, this clip path does not work as expected on API 19+ and nothing is drawn at all (everything is clipped). It works ok on API < 19.

What's wrong ?

Comment: it might be a bug, you should consider filing a bug report